# Do I forward my link-local IPV6 for gaming?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have been running some latency test on my Xbox and came across a confusing issue.

I have searched this before resorting to ask some professionals - on the advance settings of Xbox there is a IPV6 section with:

IPV6-

```
Ip Address: 2603:8080:::::
Link local: fe80::92a8::::
Gateway: fe80::ea9f::::
```

So which one do I actually use to forward my QoS packets?

Comment: link local would make no sense, ever, since it's **local** you'd - try your public (2603:) address

Comment: Thanks will do - just looking for the proper input.

Comment: what is this `proper input` you mention?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to with `forward`?

Comment: Your question is very terse on details. What is the confusing issue you are facing? What about the title, what forwarding are you referring to? What do you mean by "your QoS packets"?